# Удалить подстроку в строке?

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения, javascript

Строка вида:

```
var str = "some text [[[[test 1]] test 2]] other text";
```

Как удалить все что в квадратных скобках, включая сами скобки?

Мое решение:

```
new_str = str.replace(/\[.*\]\].*\]\]/gi,"");
```

Не совсем подходит, что не так?

**обновился** как посоветовали:

```
var str = "some text [[[[test 1]] test 2]] other text";

new_str = str.replace(/\[\[(.)+\[\[(.)+\]\] \]\]/i,'');

alert(new_str);
```

В итоге всю строку возвращает.

[fiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/atMqj/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну у вас всего одна открытая скобка слева, а их две.

```
REGEX: #\[\[(.)+\[\[(.)+\]\] \]\]#i
```

Должно работать.

Либо + заменить на * если там может и не быть символов.

Для первого примера работает, а вот это для второго:

```
/\[\[\[\[(.)+\]\](.)+\]\]/gi
```

Ваш код:

```
var str = "some text [[[[test 1]] test 2]] other text";

new_str = str.replace(/\[\[\[\[(.)+\]\](.)+\]\]/gi,'');

alert(new_str);
```

Можно даже и так:

```
/\[.*\]/gi
```

Comment: дело в том что могут быть даже переводы строки.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/atMqj/

Comment: Добавьте модификатор g и символы забоя в начале и в конце регулярного выражения.

Comment: неа, не помог g

Comment: да, чувствую, еще раз извиняюсь, от руки писал.

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что именно вам нужно. [Например](http://jsfiddle.net/97PmJ/)

```
str = str.replace(/\[\[.*\]\]/gm, "");
```

---

Как правильно заметил [[@GenchiK](/users/5414/genchik)](/users/5414/genchik) в комментариях, возможно, вам нужно просто

```
str = str.replace(/\[.*\]/gm, "");
```

если скобки не обязательно двойные.

---

Чтобы избежать проблем с переводом строк, обратите внимание, что точка [не матчит](http://simonwillison.net/2004/sep/20/newlines/) перевод строки. Так что вам надо [вот что](http://jsfiddle.net/97PmJ/1/):

```
str = str.replace(/\[[\s\S]*\]/gm, "");
```

Comment: Неправильное выражение.

Comment: @GenchiK: аргументировать сможете? Синтаксис верен, см. ссылку. С задачей справляется, см. ссылку. Никаких дополнительных требований ТС не выдвигал.

Comment: А что тут аргументировать? Запустите и посмотрите!

Comment: А да работает! Пардон! Ставлю +.

Comment: @GenchiK: вы имеете в виду `/\[.*\]/gm`? Да, пожалуй вы правы.

Comment: Да, я что-то слишком конкретно написал, а можно и короче =)

Comment: @GenchiK: Спасибо! Поскольку ТС не сказал, что именно ему надо, возможно, более конкретное выражение правильнее.

Comment: `str = str.replace(/\[.*\]/gm, "");` вполне неплохо, но все равно какой-то глюк что ли, в общем в строке кучу переводов остается кусок текста `test 2]]`, тут и на фидле все нормально будет, а так... я там уже этот кусок текста вручную заменяю, в принципе он почти в статике, ладно, спасибо!

Comment: @Maris: см. обновление ответа.